# Is there a way to assign CRD to deploy pod to the specific node?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. Is there a way to assign pod by CRD to the specific Node under the Operator pattern?

I tried to use both `nodeSelector` and affinity for `operator.yaml` and each `CRDs.yaml`,
but it is effective for the operator only.

How can I assign pod by CRDs to the specific node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've passed the nodeSelector/affinity from Custom Resource (CR) spec to Pod spec.

While creating the Pod,

```
pod.spec.containers.nodeSelector = crd.spec.<your-path>.nodeSelector
```